# How does A.super.foo() work in defender methods (Java 8)?

Tags: java

I was implementing a practical implementation of the defender(default) methods in Java 8 wherein I have a default settin for a page and some additional features for specific pages. Basically, I had to call the default method first followed by the overriden method as shown in the following Example:

```
 interface A {

    default void foo() {
        System.out.println("This is default foo method of interface A");
    }
}

class B implements A {

    public void foo() {
        A.super.foo();            //This statement is confusing
        System.out.println("This method is from class B");

    }

}
```

After some searching, I found a way to do the same using the A.super.foo() but didn't quite understand how this statement worked. 
Also when I checked the variables and methods of interface A (by giving the 'A.' (dot) in Eclipse I could only see only 2 variables, namely 'this' and 'class'. No super was present.

**How does this A.super.foo() exactly work?** Please help.

Comment: The syntax A.super.foo() seems to be similar to A.this, a qualified super reference. Since defender methods gives you a sort of multiple inheritance, super becomes ambigious and you need to qualify it with A.super.

Comment: It works by calling the method foo() defined in the superinterface A. What exactly is the question? Just because Eclipse hasn't properly implemented auto-completion yet for Java 8 specific features doesn't mean that the instruction is invalid.

Comment: @JBNizet - I know it calls the foo() method somehow and I never said that the "instruction is invalid". Just wanted to understand whats the meaning of 'A.super' as super keyword is used to refer to the parent and in this case A is already the parent.

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling - Thanks. Good answer. Reduces ambiguity for the super keyword in case of multiple inheritance.

Comment: Should consider moving the comments to a proper answer. Comments are not for answers `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax A.super.foo() seems to be similar to A.this, a qualified reference. Since defender methods gives you a sort of multiple inheritance, super becomes ambigious and you need to qualify it with A.super.